# C# LINQ Filter list of complex objects by sub-list using a list of values

Tags: c#, linq

I want to return a list of active groups that are discounted in requested states.  The list of groups each have a list of states which include the state abbrev and a discount flag.

filter criteria:

```
string[] states  //list of state abbreviations
```

List to filter:

```
public class WorksiteGroup
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsDiscontinued { get; set; }
    public List<WorksiteGroupState> ActiveStates { get; set; } = new List<WorksiteGroupState>();
}

public class WorksiteGroupState
{
    public string StateAbbrev { get; set; }
    public bool IsDiscountApplied { get; set; }
}
```

Again, I want to return a list of WorksiteGroup with the full structure above where IsDiscontinued is false and have an ActiveState where StateAbbrev matches any of the filter criteria (states[]) and IsDiscountApplied is true for that state.

Comment: If you have a list of `WorksiteGroup wsgl` then maybe try something along the lines of `var res = wsgl.where(x => x.ActiveStates.where(y => y.IsDiscountApplied))`. Start with that and see where it gets you. You seem to have a well defined problem but just haven't started coding it up yet.

Comment: Can you add a list of `WorksiteGroup` with populated data, so we can create a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do this step by step and then we can merge operations where necessary.

> I want to return a list of WorksiteGroup with the full structure above
>   where IsDiscontinued is false

```
source.Where(e => !e.IsDiscontinued);
```

> and have an ActiveState where StateAbbrev matches any of the filter
>   criteria (states[])

now let's take the previous pipeline and chain this criterion into it.

```
source.Where(e => !e.IsDiscontinued)
      .Where(e => e.ActiveStates.Any(a => states.Contains(a.StateAbbrev)))
```

> and IsDiscountApplied is true for that state.

```
source.Where(e => !e.IsDiscontinued)
      .Where(e => e.ActiveStates.Any(s => states.Contains(s.StateAbbrev) && s.IsDiscountApplied));
```

for efficiency let's swap the `Contains` call to be after `s.IsDiscountApplied` e.g.

```
source.Where(e => !e.IsDiscontinued)
      .Where(e => e.ActiveStates.Any(s => s.IsDiscountApplied && states.Contains(s.StateAbbrev)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using Linq:

```
  string[] states = new string[] { "abbrev1", "abbrev2" };

  var list = new List<WorksiteGroup>();

  var item = new WorksiteGroup();
  item.Name = "Test1";
  item.IsDiscontinued = false;
  var subitem = new WorksiteGroupState();
  subitem.IsDiscountApplied = true;
  subitem.StateAbbrev = "abbrev1";
  item.ActiveStates.Add(subitem);
  list.Add(item);

  item = new WorksiteGroup();
  item.Name = "Test2";
  item.IsDiscontinued = true;
  subitem = new WorksiteGroupState();
  subitem.IsDiscountApplied = true;
  subitem.StateAbbrev = "abbrev1";
  item.ActiveStates.Add(subitem);
  list.Add(item);

  var result = list.Where(wg => wg.IsDiscontinued == false
                             && wg.ActiveStates.Where(state => state.IsDiscountApplied == true
                                                            && states.Contains(state.StateAbbrev)).Any());

  foreach ( var value in result )
    Console.WriteLine(value.Name);

  Console.ReadKey();
```

You can play with items and add more to see results.

Answer (score 0):

sudo-code but would something like below work, im sure you could do this is one line but

```cs
var worksiteGroup = Populate();

var filteredWorkSiteGroup = worksiteGroup .Where(x=>x.IsDiscontinued == false);
filteredWorkSiteGroup.ActiveStates = filteredWorkSiteGroup.ActiveStates
                                     .Where(x=> states.Contains(x.StateAbbrev)
                                         && x.IsDiscountApplied == true);
```